# how to determine logged in user in a mean stack application

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm writing an app based on mean.js boiler plate

In my server code (express) I need to make some decisions which are based on knowing who the logged in user is

I have passport local accounts implemented.

How can I determine in the server code the identity of the current logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using passport you just have to access `req.user` as it was already mentioned.

Taking a look at your gist, my guess is that some of your routes are defined much earlier than `app.use(passport.initialize());` and `app.use(passport.session());`, which means that if you receive a request to `get /opportunity_ids` (for example), `req.user` is yet to be populated.

If you go a little bit further in the stack you will notice that all the other routes are injected **after** passport is initialized in the line:

```
// Globbing routing files
config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
    require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
});
```

The solution would be to put all your custom routes defined before passport initilization in `./app/routes/**/` and let the route files be automatically globbed. `req.user` won't be undefined.

The order in which each middleware is placed is extremely important and might produce unexpected behavior if that order is changed.

Answer (score 2):

If a user is logged in, passport.js will create a user object for every request. It sets the user as a property on the request(`req.user`). You can access any properties of the user through that object. For example: `req.user.username`, `req.user.email` etc.

Comment: then I must be doing something wrong = my req.user is undefined.  here is the gist of this entire file:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/df34da0977a475056425